# Verification of Leap Year for DOB field in WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng, leap-year

I have a text field for inputting Date of Birth(DOB) as "dd/mm/yyyy" format. I like to automate the test with WebDriver for Leap Year checking for that field. I'm using Java and TestNG with WebDriver (Selenium 2). I know the formula/logic for Leap Year mentioned below:

```
(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
```

HTML code for the text field is as below:

```
<input type="text" class="text-field" id="DOB" value="" name="field(DOB)">
```

I want to verify the Leap Year checking in a certain range of year (for example 1900 - 2012). How can I design and write Test Case for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following WebDriver Java code should work well:

```
for(int year = 1900; year <= 2012; year++){
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
driver.findElement(By.id("DOB")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("DOB")).sendKeys("29/02/" + year);
}
}
```